# Locate where css is coming from

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I'm customizing the blank Magento 2 theme and having trouble finding out where some of the css instructions are coming from (I'm aware of the less system). As an example, in the footer, I see in the Inspector that it's getting a ".footer .bugs" instruction, but nowhere in my files can I locate a .bugs declaration. Can anyone help?

Comment: is css merging enabled on your magento instance?

Comment: is there any previous style is applied? if yes then from inspect element which file it is showing?

Comment: Yes, so it's compiling the CSS. I realize I can override with a custom css, but I prefer to customize it from the first place (not "fight" the default). Any idea where the file is that commands, for example, where the body font is set, or changing the .logo float setting?

Comment: check the merging option in admin and disable css merging , also show what path it is currently showing in inspect element?